# What happens when you make a free app paid?

Tags: ios-appstore

My app has always(4 months) been free and I am wondering if I make it paid, will it be in the new paid apps category?

It is not new in sense of app but new in sense of paid app.

Comment: Don't know from personal experience but I doubt that it would be put into a "new app" category.

Answer (score 1):

That's up to Apple.  They decide what apps to feature.  The App Store gets thousands of new/updated apps every day and not every new app will be featured.  If your app provides some special service or interesting presentation, it's possible your app will be featured.